# how to resize a image with TCPDF in docker

Tags: php, docker, image, slim, tcpdf

running in test-problems with TCPDF

i am using docker container in the newest version with ubuntu 22. PHP 8.2

for my deployment of a micro service created with slim-micro-framework.

local I can render some jpg-files for the header.

`$this->Image('Images/group-logo.jpg', 68, 3, 78, 32, 'JPG', 'https://www.tcpdf.org', 'T', true, 300, false, false, false, 0, false, false, false);`

but after the deployment, the test were running in errors.

my solution is to use
$html = '

';

writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

is there any solution to use the Image-Function with resize a image ?!?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Image() function provides parameters for specifying the width and height of the image. Can you provide more information about the error message?